# How can I rotate the pivot point of my object without rotating the object itself?

Tags: transforms

I'm trying to import a 3dmodel into unreal but i need the local transform to match the global or else unreal will garble the objects' rotation/scale/translation.

Is there a way to do this in blender?  I see people doing it in every video on 3ds Max.

Comment: I think you should just use the shortcut keys alt+r right?

Comment: @YusaMac205 What does that do?  It did not align the local transform to the global.  It rotated the local according to some formula but it also rotated the object.

Comment: Why would you rotate the pivot point? Just set the directions of the axis's upon export...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some headscratching about what you mean, I figured it out. Use the shortcut CTRL+A, then apply "Rotation and Scale"

[image]

**EDIT**
What this does is it simply applies your rotation and scale of the object, aligning the local Z axis with the global Z axis and so on. It also applies the scale of the object, meaning textures will align properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution doesn't quite work because I'm starting with a model that has already been rotated and scaled.  Each wheel appears to have been transformed multiple times, in different sequences.  If I press C-a (and choose rotation & scale), my local transform still does not align with my global transform.

Comment: Simply do this for all the objects. This is the only way of doing this as far as I know of, and I reckon that there isn't that many alternatives to doing this. I used this method when exporting my objects to UE4. If you have some local values used by a constraint or something, then you have to find another way. Most likely meaning you have to re-insert values into your modifiers.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but I imagine this would get quite maddening for complex models.

Comment: Yes, it will. But there are always workarounds, and with enough knowledge you should be able to correct this at a later stage even if you have exported it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use our free addon BS Modify Pivot, with it you can change the object pivot location and orientation in a similar fashion to what you can do in 3dsmax with "Affect Pivot Only"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrYGXg5HjMA

Hope it´s useful.

Cheers!

Comment: Why is it that anytime i need to do something basic in blender that all of the other software can do out if the box i need a 3rd party plugin...

Answer (score 1):

@FreeMox: You want to change the pivot point in other applications because various tools/particles what ever use the pivot points direction for certain things, so you have to make sure the pivot point is positioned and rotated correctly to have the results you wanna achieve. Blender works a little different though. I also looked for a way to rotate it but the ctrl+a option was in the end the way to go ;)